# Spring boot profile sync maven profile

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

i have a Spring Boot application. I need to connect spring boot profile to maven profile so than when i am calling command

```
mvn clean install -Pdev
```

or

```
mvn clean install -Pprod
```

it should call spring boot to load application-dev.yml or application-prod.yml. And when i call

```
mvn clean install
```

it should call application-dev.yml file before startup. So spring boot dev profile needs to be called from 2 commands. I have a problem every time i switch profile it builds application from default profile. So can you please help me to wire maven and spring boot profile.
Here is my pom.xml

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
                <profiles>${spring-profiles}</profiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <spring-profiles>dev</spring-profiles>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <spring-profiles>prod</spring-profiles>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Here is application.yml example.

```
spring:
devtools:
    restart :
        enabled: true
    livereload:
        enabled: false  
datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    database: MYSQL
    show_sql: true
    properties:
        hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
        hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
        hibernate.generate_statistics: true
        hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: update


server:
port: 8080
compression:
  enabled: true
  mime-types : application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain,application/javascript,text/css,text/html
session :
  timeout : 540000
mail:
smtp:
  starttls.enable: true
  auth: true
  port: 587
activation:
  expiration.hours: 24
  template: /mails/activationEmail.html
change-password:
  template: /mails/passwordResetEmail.html
```

Difference between application-dev.yml, application-prod.yml is only in port. So that I only change port when i change mvn profile before deploy.

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand everything you want but you have two options to get some stuff working.

First, in one of your maven profiles you can set one as per default:

```
<profile>
   <id>dev</id>
   <activation>
       <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
   </activation>
```

So there is no need to give a maven profile for `mvn clean install`

The other option is to set variables to your profile and get those values to your `application.properties` file when building the app.

For example for your port you can go like that:

```
<profile>
    <id>dev</id>
    <properties>
        <serverPort>9999</serverPort>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

And in your application.properties file you can get the value by using `@serverPort`:

```
server.port=@serverPort@
```

If you now build your app by using any profile you will get the value set in your maven profile.

Comment: i want to switch spring boot profiles via switching maven profiles. So when i build project for example with maven prod profile. It uses spring boot profile with name prod to build project by using application-prod.ymp prop file.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what is described in documentation.